How to obtain credentials for the Zoho SDK in self client mode?
This took an unnecessarily long time to figure out, and neither the Zoho documentation, help, nor code samples were useful.  I found some off-hand references to Postman (the app) in a mention elsewhere, and it finally dawned on me:
Zoho automates part of the credential setup via their website, then they expect you to figure out the next several steps without explaining it or providing a simple onboarding per-method.  It appears from many comments that support does not understand that their documentation is indeed opaque in this regard.
This general method for self client will likely be a reasonable explainer for the other Zoho sdks as well.

This is incredibly convoluted and requires the use of a third party app such as Postman (or forming an HTTP POST request another way, within the time allotted).
To use the Zoho API, you must have an access_token.  To obtain an access_token, you must utilize the grant code, which is generated after creating the client id and client secret in the api console page.
@see https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v6/auth-request.html

Create clientID and clientSecret on the developer api console https://api-console.zoho.com
Generate code on the next tab, with ZohoCRM.modules.ALL and 10 minutes.  Choose production, copy the grant token.
NOW you have to manually create a POST.   Download the Postman app and setup the following:

type POST
url https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token (pay attention to the docs, your base url may change based on your location)
params:
grant_type=authorization_code
client_id=<from api console>
client_secret=<from api console>
redirect_uri=nothing
code=<grant code from api console>




Success from the POST result in postman should contain the access_token and refresh_token.

NOW you can provide these to the OAuthBuilder in the sdk such as:
    $token = (new OAuthBuilder())
      ->clientId($_ENV['ZOHO_CLIENT_ID'])
      ->clientSecret($_ENV['ZOHO_CLIENT_SECRET'])
      ->accessToken($_ENV['ZOHO_ACCESS_TOKEN'])
      ->refreshToken($_ENV['ZOHO_REFRESH_TOKEN'])
      ->build();

